# How to make onChange() work when you change it via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select list.

```
<select id="cars">
<option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
<option value="Subaru">Subaru</option>
<option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
</select>
```

The onchange works well if you select the option by yourself.

```
$('#cars').on('change', function (e) {
var valueSelected = this.value;
alert(valueSelected);
});
```

However, if you use jquery to select a value;

```
$("#cars").val("Toyota");
```

It changes the option, but it doesnt trigger the jquery function. What is the correct approach to trigger that ?

Comment: have you tried $('#cars').trigger('change')... EDIT: nevermind, answered below

Comment: If youre still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Comment: Forgot to mark, it solved thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**trigger**](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```js
$('#cars').on('change', function(e) {
  var valueSelected = this.value;
  console.log(valueSelected);
});

$("#cars").val("Toyota");
$("#cars").trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cars">
  <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
  <option value="Subaru">Subaru</option>
  <option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
</select>
```